# json and Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I have trouble with Spring MVC and json.

I use SimplecartJS to generate json data like this :

```
  {"currency":"RUR",
    "shipping":250,
    "tax":0,
    "taxRate":0,
    "itemCount":2,
    "item_name_1":"Name of product #1",
    "item_quantity_1":6,
    "item_price_1":159,
    "item_options_1":"",
    "item_name_2":"Name of product #2",
    "item_quantity_2":2,
    "item_price_2":159,
    "item_options_2":"",
    "form":{
    "Fname":"UserName",
    "Phone":"7123456789",
    "Address":"UserAddress",
    "Comment":"Comment Text"
    }
}
```

My controller Spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkorder2", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public String test (@RequestBody OrderCon orderC)throws Exception{


            ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
            om.canSerialize(OrderCon.class);
            System.out.println(om);


        return test(orderC);
    }
```

Code from client side

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8080/url' 
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
            },
          contentType:'application/json',
          dataType: "json", 
          type: "POST", 
          url: url, 
          data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

And my question:

When I send data to controller, I have a mistake 400 Bad request. The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. When adding a new item field name will "item_name_2","item_name_3"  etc. How I can parse this. I try parse to List, Set but it is not working. Please help.

UPD1: OrderCon.java

```
public class OrderCon {

    private List<String> form;
    private List<List<String>> json; 

getters and setters...
 }
```

Comment: Post your OrderCon class.

Comment: Added OrderCon class

Comment: Can you create a class for `Item` wit the fields `name, quantity, price, options` and then have a List of these on the `OrderCon` class?

Comment: @Leon I tried this, but when adding new item item_name_+i, i++ for example "item_name_1" >> "item_name_2" >> "item_name_3" etc.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that you do not add numbers to the items. Do you need the numbers?

Comment: @Leon it a simplecartjs code here https://github.com/wojodesign/simplecart-js/blob/master/simpleCart.js string # 1156. I will try edit it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you are going to be able to parse that data to a class like you have, since you need to add dynamic properties to a Java class.

You do however have two options to get the data out

First option is parse the json to a HasMap of Strings, ie. change your controller signature to

```
public String test (@RequestBody Map<String, String> orderC)
```

The other option is to use a JsonNode and deal with the data as a tree, here is an example http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel

I personally would try the latter first

Answer (score 0):

You're getting **400 Bad Request** because Spring is trying to map the passed JSON directly to your OrderCon class.

For this to work, the class would need to map to the keys specified in the JSON.

IE:

JSON:

```
{ 
  "name" : "foo", 
  "phone": "111-111-1111" 
}
```

would map to:

```
public class someJsonPojo(){

  String name;
  String phone;

  //setters & getters

}
```

I don't think this will work well since instead of getting an array of items, you only get an item appended to the list as a new key:value. You should be able to modify the JSON so that you can map to an array of `Item` objects, which contain the name, quantity, price, etc.